# log4j not rotating logs when there is not activity

Tags: tomcat, log4j

log4j not rotating logs(tomcat server logs catalina.log and localhost.log) when there is not activity. here is my log4j.properties. but if the log has activity then the logs are rotating. please advice any help appreciated

> Log4j version:- log4j-1.2.17.jar

```
 log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CATALINA

    log4j.appender.CATALINA=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.CATALINA.File=${catalina.base}/logs/catalina.out
    log4j.appender.CATALINA.Append=true
    log4j.appender.CATALINA.Encoding=UTF-8
    log4j.appender.CATALINA.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm
    log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

    log4j.appender.LOCALHOST=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.File=${catalina.base}/logs/localhost.log
    log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.Append=true
    log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.Encoding=UTF-8
    log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm
    log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

    log4j.appender.MANAGER=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.MANAGER.File=${catalina.base}/logs/manager.log
    log4j.appender.MANAGER.Append=true
    log4j.appender.MANAGER.Encoding=UTF-8
    log4j.appender.MANAGER.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm
    log4j.appender.MANAGER.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.MANAGER.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

    log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.File=${catalina.base}/logs/host-manager.log
    log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.Append=true
    log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.Encoding=UTF-8
    log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm
    log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

    log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Encoding=UTF-8
    log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

    # Configure which loggers log to which appenders
    log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost]=INFO, LOCALHOST
    log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager]=\
      INFO, MANAGER
    log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager]=\
      INFO, HOST-MANAGER
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected with a `DailyRollingFileAppender` as the rollover occurs as part of the subAppend() method when something is actually logged. The Javadoc for this method states:

> Before actually logging, this method will check whether it is time to
>   do a rollover. If it is, it will schedule the next rollover time and
>   then rollover.

If you have a requirement for the file to rotate at midnight - it may be easiest to schedule a log message at 00:00:00. This will trigger the log file to roll over. If you're using JEE you may be able to do something like:

```
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class RollLogs {
        static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RollLogs.class);
    @Schedule(second="0", minute="0", hour="0", dayOfWeek="*", persistent=false)
    public void rollLogs() {
        logger.info("midnight");
    }
}
```